# с++ не работает условие

Tags: c++, циклы, условия

цикл while срабатывает и при значениях j больше размера массива

```
int k = 0;
int s = a.size() + 1;
for (int i = 0; i < a.size() - 1; i++)
{
    int j = i + 1;
    while ((a[j] != a[i])||(j < a.size()))
    {
        j++;
    }
    if (j - i < s) { s = j - i; k = a[i]; }
}
```

Comment: Видимо из-за того, что `a[j] != a[i]` выполняется? Можете сделать [mcve]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А что удивительного?

```
(a[j] != a[i]) || (j < a.size())
```

Если за пределами массива вернется `a[j]` (а тут UB, может быть что угодно...), не равное `a[i]`, то первая часть условия истинна, а значит, истинно и все выражение.

Вы, наверное, хотели написать

```
(j < a.size()) && (a[j] != a[i])
```

и именно в указанном порядке!